# Are the Office Web Components broken and dead?

Tags: windows-7, activex, spreadsheet, office-web-components

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Components) on Wikipedia®:

> "The Pivot Table and Spreadsheet web components do not function on Windows 7."

Is this going to be fixed?

Comment: Why not ask Microsoft directly?

Comment: I thought it would be faster.  Also, I trust SO more than Microsoft.

Comment: That article only apply to OWC11, try your luck by switching to OWC10 or OWC12 (though if the problem is related to Windows 7's change in UAC or MSOLAP the other versions may not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After personally testing the OWC on Windows 7, it does appear broken.

Answer (score 0):

I totally disagree. I can use OWC in a WEBPAGE quite easily.  It works flawlessly on Windows 7. On the other hand, I can't use OWC inside of an Access form because I use Office 2010 64-bit.